Why is std::bit_cast allowed on pointers?
std::bit_cast is advertised as the safe alternative to type-punning via reinterpret_cast. However, I see very often that people just blindly replace reinterpret_cast with bit_cast and calls it a day:
float x{};
-int y = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);
+int y = *std::bit_cast<int*>(&x);

Which is not just obviously wrong, but entirely bypasses all compiler and linter warnings. I have seen std::bit_cast hiding an illegal combination of both reinterpret_cast plus const_cast, which would be totally banned in code review.
So, why did they allow this? What is the use case of std::bit_cast on pointers?

I mean, why not? You might want to reinterpret some bits as a pointer (or vice versa).

Isn't that what reinterpret_cast is for? What problem does std::bit_cast solve in that case?

This question is similar to: Why was std::bit_cast added, if reinterpret_cast could do the same?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@user1011113 bit_cast accepts more combinations of types than reinterpret_cast (and shouldn't be used in its place, yes). It would seem weird to specifically ban casting pointers to pointers, while it otherwise accepts any two types that have the same size (and satisfy some other conditions).

@Jean-BaptisteYunès Looks unrelated. That question talks about type punning via reinterpret_cast, while this one is about reinterpreting the bit representation of a pointer itself.

You understand that std::bit_cast<T>(x) is (somewhat) equivalent to *reinterpret_cast<T *>(&x), right? (Apart from the latter usually being UB.) So std::bit_cast<int *>(&x) is actually equivalent to float *y = &x; *reinterpret_cast<int **>(&y).

std::bit_cast should certainly be allowed on pointers, but I fail to see an obvious reason why it should be allowed between pointers (i.e. casting one pointer to another pointer of incompatible type), which is what the question body seems to focus on.

@HolyBlackCast absolutely not. bit_cast<T> copies the bytes of the object into another object, which is well-defined behavior. A copy is not aliasing. reinterpret_cast does not make a copy, it only creates an alias (which may invoke UB).

Yes, note the "Apart from the latter usually being UB" part. The point I'm making is that std::bit_cast<T> doesn't correspond to reinterpret_cast<T>, but rather to reinterpret_cast<T *>.

@user1011113 "What problem does std::bit_cast solve in that case?" -- Why must it solve a problem in every case for which it is defined?

std::bit_casting between unrelated pointer types casts the pointer just as reinterpret_cast does.  If the pointers are unrelated, dereferencing the resultant pointer is still Undefined Behaviour.

Disallow it would indeed be safer. But, I'm pretty sure we can have correct usage of std::bitcast with pointers (even if above usage is indeed wrong).

"but entirely bypasses all compiler and linter warnings." Those can be improved for that pattern though.

I found now the paper introducing std::bit_cast:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0476r1.html#r0r1
Version R0 did have logic to prevent it from being used on pointers, but it was dropped in R1 with following comment:

The pointer-forbidding logic was removed. It was initially there to help developers when a better tool is available, but it’s easily worked around (e.g. with a struct containing a pointer). Note that this doesn’t prevent constexpr versions of bit_cast: the implementation is allowed to error out on bit_cast of pointer.

With voting:

bit_cast should allow pointer types in To and From. SF F N A SA 4 5 4 2 1

My interpretation is then that std::bit_cast with pointers is useful because it can be used in constexpr contexts, unlike reinterpret_cast. Adding extra safety is not useful either because it's easily worked around anyway.
My understanding is also that it's not the responsibility of C++ as a language to prevent misuse of libraries - compilers or linters should do that instead.

Even simplest,workarounds need extra effort. The extra effort is mirrored with extra syntax. All that means cheating is uggly. Workaround is not a good excuse for letting wrong behavior slip. A double bit_cast can easily circumvent the check, but it shouldn't mean that the most obvious errors should be overlooked.

"My interpretation is then that std::bit_cast with pointers is useful because it can be used in constexpr contexts, unlike reinterpret_cast": You are misunderstanding the comment. Originally the restriction for pointers would make it so that this bit_cast between pointers wouldn't need to be supported in constexpr context (by virtue of being unsupported in all contexts). That was as intended, because it shouldn't be possible to cast between pointer representations at compile-time (for the same reason that reinterpret_cast between pointers is not allowed).

The comment notes that a general provision about unspecified behavior in library functions allows the implementation to still not support pointers in a constexpr context regardless. In the end it was specified more clearly: If any (sub)object of the source or destination is of pointer type, then std::bit_cast isn't a constant subexpression, i.e. can't be used in a mandatory constexpr context. That's the intended behavior, because the result of using std::bit_cast on pointer values would have specification and implementation issues.

"shouldn't be possible to cast between pointer representations at compile-time" assumes a desktop-class general-purpose computing system.  When targetting embedded systems, there most certainly are reasons to work with physical memory addresses (pointer representations) including at compile time.
